# how to project grouping into object in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to do a simple GROUP BY/COUNT in mongodb with this aggregation query:

```
{
  $match:{
    'os':7
  }
},
{
  $group : {
    _id:"$status", 
    count:{$sum:1}
  }
},
{
  $project:{
    count:1,
    status:1
  }
}
```

It's return an array like this

```
[{ "_id" : "ENC", "count" : 18 }
{ "_id" : "INT", "count" : 363 }
{ "_id" : "ANN", "count" : 132 }]
```

Is there a way to project the result in an object, using the grouping field as a key ? 
For example:

```
{
   ENC:18, 
   INT:363, 
   ANN:132
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think MongoDB's aggregation framework has [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operations that can convert field values into keys. You could try convert the aggregation result using the [**`forEach()`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.forEach) cursor method to iterate over the projected fields and use JavaScript's **[bracket-notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors)** on the result object to then create desired final object:

```
var result = [
    { "_id" : "ENC", "count" : 18 },
    { "_id" : "INT", "count" : 363 },
    { "_id" : "ANN", "count" : 132 }
];
var obj = {};
result.forEach(function (doc){
    obj[doc._id] = doc.count;
});
printjson(obj); // {ENC: 18, INT: 363, ANN: 132}
```